# ddwrt:IfNew doesn't work in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ddwrt

I used to use the ddwrt:IfNew in SP 2007 to show if docs or items are new but trying the below doesn't work. Any ideas....

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:IfNew(string(@Created))">
    <img alt="" src="../images/GMAILNEW.gif" width="16" height="16" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Oops you have to use :@Created_x0020_Date.ifnew instead

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. Please leave your comment as an answer next time, and then you can gain reputation for it as well!

Answer (score 1):

*Comment as answer from OP:*

You have to use :@Created_x0020_Date.ifnew instead.